# TS - types - omit field in parameter object in function while keeping types

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

I have a type that omits specified fields in functions parameter object like this:

```
type OmitFields<F, K extends string> = F extends (props: infer P) => infer R ? (props: Omit<P, K>) => R : never;
```

And use it like:

```
type Omitted = OmitFields<typeof functionWithObjectParam, 'first' | 'second'>
```

How can I make type parameter K be aware of type that props object gets inferred as, and restrict correct strings to its keys?

Comment: What is `functionWithObjectParam`? Where specifically would you like to see the restriction enforced?  
Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/NlvolW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: @jcalz with total respect for your constructive criticism of this question ... I found that I could, in fact, paste this into the playground and give it a try, and I understand pretty well what `functionWithObjectParam` is without it being given explicitly as part of the question. That might be a way of improving it, nonetheless. I voted up the question because to me, it does not seem trivial, we need someone with advanced TS chops to solve it, or tell us it can't be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
type OmitFields<
    F extends (props: any) => any,
    K extends keyof Parameters<F>[0],
> = (props: Omit<Parameters<F>[0], K>) => ReturnType<F>
```

Here `F` is constrained to be a function that takes one argument. And `K` is constrained to the keys of that argument.

Then you can reconstruct the function type without any fancy `infer` stuff.

This seems to do what you want:

```
function functionWithObjectParam(props: { a: number, b: number }) {}

type Omitted = OmitFields<typeof functionWithObjectParam, 'b'> // ok
type OmittedBad = OmitFields<typeof functionWithObjectParam, 'bad'> // Type '"bad"' does not satisfy the constraint '"b" | "a"'.(2344)

declare const fn: Omitted

fn({ a: 1 }) // ok

fn({ a: 1, b: 2 })
// Argument of type '{ a: number; b: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Omit<{ a: number; b: number; }, "b">'.
//   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'b' does not exist in type 'Omit<{ a: number; b: number; }, "b">'.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gtgS2AMQRANgEwM4B4CwAUFCVMlBAB7AQB2OUAFGAE4D2Y2AXFAIa0gAlFAC8APj4CANEVJQA0hWp0GAawgg2AMygAFXi15wINFnmRiA2gAYAujMISRTVh26xEwXPsPHT5qzspBTFhcSgAJRMAVxZaABVwCFwLIiItaNoAY2AENlooDOzc-IB1JAALGAAjACsIHJ8jZnZOHgBvPh5aaLhqiBZg6u7e-pYoAF9hdom0wlBIDyQaTFEllDQsPAWIbULMnLzacuAquobgJrhggHJqm4kAekeoNlUiHfWVgCFeVed4EhUBgcLgdnsiocypUavVGgYjLdqn8HlBnlBEosbgAiZGYbE3KCYNgQbBQWhsYBQbC8XLYLQgKCnaBZfLYYCGBC0Kk46rYqAAHyg2N4BIAdIwAEwAZgALLLBHNMA10AYWWyqVpaDxAcAVulaIxOrweABGSaKwhao1dKCmoY8SUWoA)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TypeScript utility type [`Parameters`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) instead of inferring the type of your F function 1st argument (`props`).

> Constructs a tuple type from the types used in the parameters of a function type `Type`.

From there, you can directly be more specific to constrain your `K` generic, instead of just `extends string`: for example `K extends keyof Parameters<F>[0]`

Now to be even closer to your example, we could make it so F can be something else than a function, in which case the conditions are slightly more complicated, but still do-able:

```
type OmitFields<
  F,
  K extends (
    F extends (...args: any) => any
      ? keyof Parameters<F>[0]
      : string
  )
> = F extends (...args: any) => infer R
  ? (props: Omit<Parameters<F>[0], K>) => R
  : never;

declare function functionWithObjectParam(props: { key1: number; second: boolean; }): string;

type Omitted = OmitFields<typeof functionWithObjectParam, 'first' | 'second'>
  // TS2344 Type '"first" | "second"' does not satisfy the constraint '"second" | "key1"'. Type '"first"' is not assignable to type '"second" | "key1"'.

type Omitted2 = OmitFields<typeof functionWithObjectParam, 'key1' | 'second'> // Okay

type Omitted3 = OmitFields<string, 'first' | 'second'> // Okay
```

However I suspect that in your case the conditional type was only to enable type inference. In the case you can have a type that accepts only functions, it becomes much simpler:

```
type OmitFields2<
  F extends (...args: any) => any,
  K extends keyof Parameters<F>[0]
> = (props: Omit<Parameters<F>[0], K>) => ReturnType<F>

type Omitted4 = OmitFields2<typeof functionWithObjectParam, 'first' | 'second'>
  // TS2344 Type '"first" | "second"' does not satisfy the constraint '"second" | "key1"'.

type Omitted5 = OmitFields2<typeof functionWithObjectParam, 'key1' | 'second'> // Okay

type Omitted6 = OmitFields2<string, 'first' | 'second'>
  // TS2344 Type 'string' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'.
```

[Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=34&ssc=83&pln=23&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gtgS2AMQRANgEwM4B4BQUUyANIVANJQQAewEAdjlABTlHLV2PMsB0AgIYAnAObYAXFEEMQASigBeAHzTZ7IlAD8UANYQQAewBmUAAojBcCPWF5kygNoAGALoaiU7MGEIGo8jl8VUViLnombFYBPhFxKRl5JVU-YwhhKAAlch0WMGFDMElYRGBcC2ErG3T7JzcSSmUFFSzyKQYIADd0gG58fEwIAGN0EWhjAFcGIeAEQwYoSenZ%20YB1JAALGAAjACth4AqrPIKiqQBvPQMARnaJuG3eqGxh%20cwpbcNDdAgZHqgAL5yLw%20PyiPr4UCQEpIeiYJQwlBoLB4KEQEyLKYzOYMdbALZ7A5HOANADkxgQdmApKgAB8oKSXkM3qTlOQAPTsqAAFQAygAmADMABZhTzwNBSQAiClUqV0qBSplvKU0zCGCBRBiGYDPQSzbDGEBQfHQZkMbyVPy66XKpjy%20lS-Qga6qvji6HS2XeVVQBBanXSbDYBCiBiCbY-E2GE0ShlK172hVOm5u-poxFw-kI%20BIVAYHC4NEYpbYtabHb7GbEsnO640%20mMxOYVlQTmwXSCEDpuO54BwwU50r5lG4S1gsne6kKpvmluqdswTvd-qQ3vD5E4fkEDjhHhRfhCMTFRLNVSJMhEKi0CLMZ0Y4nVOy4BwudwhVj5QrFPvlSzWWxajfBoKCaZIshsCZhAYbkJRfNk12hPs4TFUI%20xHLciwlEssRWXEK0Jat-0nSlvAbBk7XnDkuT5IVRQ9SUZVI4AHUVSjfXVTUoG1XVsH1f0jRNDYzXmS1BGteN2OTOs00Q6BkIgTAAFYhzzTdsG3YtTFLPC8QJKtDmIhk63I2cWQXLkly7HskNKOEADZVKRAsNLHUF-BIqlTMo1lqJ5AURTFWDPXHfw1Q1ANeP4w1jVNKBzTEiTSUPWJjwSWQzzUEBST4fAgA)